# Why is Jsoup scraping data in Java/Android differently

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I have been trying to scrape the 'School Notices' from this URL http://www.isleworthsyon.hounslow.sch.uk/

I tried scraping the text in Java and then replaced all "   " (which I am not sure what character it is,) with a new line using String.replaceAll method and it worked absolutely fine with perfect results, but when I apply the same code to Android..it gives me different results.

IN JAVA:

```
String URL = "http://www.isleworthsyon.hounslow.sch.uk/";

Document site = null;
try {
    site = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
} catch (IOException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
}


        String HTML = site.html();

        site.select("a").remove();

        Elements news = site.select("div#np_91983-1");

        String output = news.text();


        String for_output_text = output.replaceAll("   ","\n\n");

        System.out.println(for_output_text);

}
```

}

IN ANDROID:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);

        String URL = "http://www.isleworthsyon.hounslow.sch.uk/";

        Document site = null;
        try {
            site = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        site.select("a").remove();

        Elements news = site.select("div#np_91983-1");

        String output = news.text();

        String for_output_text = output.replaceAll("   ","\n\n");

        text.setText(for_output_text);
        }
```

The two output texts are different as you can see below

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/35866688/Comparison.png

btw this is my first go at web scraping

**Edit:** After experiments, The strings I get from news.text() have different spacings in java and android. Any suggestions as to  why that is the case and are there any alternatives?

Comment: As a point of interest, it's still "in Java" when running on Android. But you haven't described what's different, only shown two essentially identical chunks of code.

Comment: Sorry, I know both are in Java, but I couldn't come up with a term quickly enough that would differentiate them. Btw, I have upadted the question.

Comment: please debug your code and compare the strings using diff instead of just looking at the TextView

Comment: Can you print out `output.length()` and `for_output_text.length()` as this will give us a big clue as to if the Java/Android Strings are the same. If they *are* the same length, then my money is on the `TextView` simply formatting the text differently to your `System.out.println()`.

Comment: Looks the same to me; I'd be somewhat surprised if it was anything substantial beyond output differences. You need to do an actual structural comparison.

Comment: @marcosbeirigo , I am not sure what is "diff"

Comment: @bakshi_s it's a linux command line tool usefull to check differences between two files, you can also use it online: http://diffchecker.com/

Comment: @marcosbeirigo Although I wasn't able to get the value of String out of emulator but after a lot of experiments I can confirm that both strings are different.

Comment: @PaulGrime the length of both strings (output and for_output_text) are same if you are in the same platform . But they are Different in different platform so in PC java its 509, but in Android it is 499. I guess it suggests that jsoup is parsing the text differently.

Comment: So that's 10 difference, and there *appears* to be 10 missing line breaks in the TextView. Looks like the TextView is merging \r\n together as one line break, whereas sysout is not?

Comment: @PaulGrime Also, when I assign 'news.text() ' to a String, the String.length() in the two platforms are different. Does it mean the implementation of String calss is different in the PC java and Android? or is it a problem with Jsoup? Are there any alternatives?

Comment: I have just checked something, the characters that I replace arent two spaces, they are "   ", which I am not sure what it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally! I found a better Solution; to use for loop and add each element separately.

```
final TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);

        String URL = "http://www.isleworthsyon.hounslow.sch.uk/";

        Document site = null;
        try {
            site = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        site.select("a").remove();

        Elements news = site.select("div#np_91983-1");

        Elements newsline = news.select("[align~=center]");

        String output = "";
        String  oldline = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < newsline.size(); i++) {


            String  newline = oldline + "\n" + newsline.get(i).text();  
            oldline = newline;
            output = newline;
          }           

        text.setText(output);
```

Thanks to everyone who helped